# How can I get additional form data when using an AJAX submit for TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

I'm trying to submit a form containing a tinyMCE instance using the "save" plugin and ajax. I found this article on how: https://support.ephox.com/hc/en-us/articles/226358867-Save-using-AJAX

(basically you override the normal form submission and point it to a function that uses ajax).

But how would I grab additional form data and submit it along with the tinyMCE content? I have multiple forms with the same class on the page, so referencing a field ID using jquery is not an option.

Another way of asking this is: how do I get DOM elements *relative* to the tinyMCE instance and include them in my ajax call (I know how to get the tinyMCE content into the ajax call)? Or, how can I submit the whole form using the "save" plugin in tinyMCE? (by default it just uses a traditional form submit, and using e.preventDefault in the jquery function doesn't keep normal form submission from happening)

Below is an example of my form. tinyMCE is triggered inline on the content_text field. I'm trying to use the "Save" plugin to submit the whole form via ajax, but not sure it's possible.

```
<form class="inline-content-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/contents/'. $topContent->id ) }}">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="content_id" id="content_id" value="123">

<div class='content_text'></div> 

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm update_button" style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-refresh"></i>Update/button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be optimal, but I figured out a workaround for this issue in case anyone else is struggling. I used a click event on my textarea to initiate TinyMCE, then could grab other form elements and data using normal jQuery selectors (via `parent()`, etc.); sample code:

```
$(document).on('click', ".content_text", function () {

selected_content_div_dom = $(this)[0];

selected_content_div = $(this);

var contentData = {
            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            '_method': $(this).parent().find('input[name=_method]').val(),
    };


tinymce.init({
  target:  selected_content_div_dom,
   plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars fullscreen',
    'save'
    ],
    toolbar: 'bold italic bullist numlist outdent indent link image save cancel',
    save_enablewhendirty:false,
    save_oncancelcallback: function () { console.log('Save canceled'); 
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setProgressState(true);
        $("#top_content").load("{{ url('/top_content') }}");
    },

    save_onsavecallback :  function () { 

        tinyMCE.triggerSave();

       contentData['content'] = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();


        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST", // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url: "{{ url('/contents/') }}" + "/" + content_id, // the url where we want to POST
            data: contentData, // our data object
            encode: true,
            success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
            console.log(response);


            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
            console.log("failed");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }

    });
}

    });

 });
```